# Where should behavior live when the user story mentions the parent, but the action is upon a child?

Tags: c#, class, domain-driven-design, entity

I've got a StoreOwner entity. StoreOwner has a Store property.

```
public class Product { }

public class Store { 
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}

public class StoreOwner { 
    public Store Store { get; private set }
}
```

I've got the following user story:

> As a store owner, I can add a product to my store.

Where should the behavior of "adding the product to the store" live? On the StoreOwner or the Store?

If it's the store, what would the method name be?

Comment: I assume you mean the behavior is "adding a product to the store", not "adding the store", as the latter implies something has to actually build the store itself. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put it in `Store`, as I'm guessing the products collection is a child entity in `Store`.  Something like `Store.AddProduct()` as opposed to exposing the products collection.

If there is logic to make sure only the current owner can do it, I believe this *optionally* belongs in `Store` only if `Store` already has knowledge about the owner, but should *definitely* be validated before trying to all `AddProduct`.

That part seems like a user role, so perhaps this belongs in your UI controller or if the current user is actually the store owner, perhaps factor this into the user role and authorise against it.

Answer (score 1):

> Where should the behavior of "adding the store" live? On the StoreOwner or the Store?

I assume you mean adding the product

I would have the method be a part of `Store`. Something like `store.AddProduct(product)`. You can't add a product to an owner unless it's some salon shampoo or something

Comment: What would the method name be?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best approaches I've taken is to always look at it as to who owns what.

So :

StoreOwner owns a Store
A Store contains Product

So based on your story yand the above use case you would then say Store.AddProduct( newProduct );

Answer (score 0):

If you only should be able to add a product if you have access to a `StoreOwner` instance, put the method there, otherwise in the `Store` class.

The name `AddProduct` seems obvious...